# Call Google_Client from a static method in a controller using Slim 3

Tags: php, oop, slim-3, google-client

I need to create a new user in google, and I`m using Slim 3 to make a REST API.

My code:

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "somethig": "somethig",
    "google/apiclient": "2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

routes.php:

```
$app->get('/users/create', App\Controllers\UserController::class . ':create_users');
```

UserController.php:

```
use App\Models\UserModel;

class UserController{

   public static function create_users( Request $request, Response $response, array $args )
   {
      // some code

      $users = UserModel::where( 'pending', 0 )->get(); // WORKS OK

      // some more code

      self::get_google_client();
   }


   private function get_google_client()
   {
     $client = new Google_Client(); // ERROR: Class 'App\Controllers\Google_Client'

     // a lot more code, based on quickstart.php

   }
} // class end
```

I want to access to `Google_Client` as I do with `UserModel`, but I cannot figure it out how.

If I use it in routes.php, it works.

```
$app->get('/g', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $client = new Google_Client(); // THIS WORKS!!

    var_dump($client);
});
```

The `Google_Client`class is defined in \vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\client.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Google_Client` exists in the root namespace.

When you attempt to do:

```
$client = new Google_Client()
```

It's looking for the class in the namespace for the file the statement is in.

It works in *routes.php* because there are is no namespace declared in that file. But since your controller does reside in a namespace, you get the error you are seeing.

To avoid it, just do this:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
```

To explicitely say that `Google_Client` resides in the root namespace.